# How to deduce the return type of a lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction, generic-lambda

I want to mimic Ruby's `map()` method in C++. I am struggling to figure out the return type automatically:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::string T2;

template<class T1,
//  class T2, // gives "couldn't deduce template parameter 'T2'"
    class UnaryPredicate>
std::vector<T2> map(std::vector<T1> in, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    std::vector<T2> res(in.size());
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), res.begin(), pred);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1({1,2,3});
    auto v2(map(v1, [](auto el) { return "'"+std::to_string(el+1)+"'"; }));
    std::cout << v2[0] << "," << v2[1] << "," << v2[2] << std::endl;
}
```

This way it compiles, but `T2` is fixed to `string`. If I use the other `T2` definition the compiler complains `couldn't deduce template parameter 'T2'`.
I also tried to make use of `std::declval`, but probably not the right way - I was unable to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Just FYI, please note that the correct signature of the main function is `int main()`.

Comment: Mimicking `map` is not necessarily that good of an idea now that we have ranges. `ranges::view::transform` is idiomatic and efficient, and if you need a copy rather than a view, just make a copy of the view.

Comment: @ruohola That isn't impossible, but it is very likely that the legacy implicit-int rule kicked in.  Some compilers still implement it by default.  See [implicit int and implicit declaration of functions with gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11171120) for example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `decltype` + `std::decay_t`:

```
template <class T, class UnaryPredicate>
auto map(const std::vector<T>& in, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    using result_t = std::decay_t<decltype(pred(in[0]))>;

    std::vector<result_t> res;
    res.reserve(in.size());
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(res), pred);
    return res;
}
```

Example usage:

```
std::vector v1{1, 2, 3};
auto v2 = map(v1, [](int el) { return "'" + std::to_string(el + 1) + "'"; });
std::cout << v2[0] << ", " << v2[1] << ", " << v2[2] << '\n';
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9Ywx8dFcRbpP4NGW))

Please also note the following changes that I made:

1. I changed `in` to take by const reference instead of by value.  This avoids unnecessary copies.
2. I used `reserve` + `back_inserter`, instead of value initialization + assignment.
3. I used `auto` as the return type.  This enables return type deduction.  The `res` vector is guaranteed not to be copied.  It is also eligible for copy elision.
4. You can list-initialize from a *braced-init-list* directly, so remove the parentheses surrounding the *braced-init-list*.
5. `std::endl` should not be used when `\n` is sufficient.  `std::endl` causes the buffer to be flushed, while `\n` does not.  Unnecessary flushing can cause performance degradation.  See [`std::endl` vs `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907).

Answer (score 4):

To simplify use `auto` as return type, and `value_type` of vector can be specified by `declval` - call `UnaryPredicate` for `T1`:

```
template<class T1,
    class UnaryPredicate>
auto map(std::vector<T1> in, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    std::vector< decltype(std::declval<UnaryPredicate>()(T1{})) > res(in.size());
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), res.begin(), pred);
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4bNGnd)